# Bind a <List> to an ObjectDataSource (c# and Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, objectdatasource

I have a GridView that I'm binding from my database table "Publishers".  The "Publishers" table has 22,000+ rows inside it and every bind event is taking a **LONG** time.

I have implemented custom paging by using the following technique:

```
public class PublisherDataSource
{
    public List<Publisher> GetPublishers(int startIndex, int maxRows)
    {
        using (CA_Entities db = new CA_Entities ())
        {
            return (from publisher in db.Publishers
                    select publisher)
                        .Where(p => p.isActive == true)
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDT)
                        .ThenBy(p => p.SiteURL)
                        .Skip(startIndex)
                        .Take(maxRows).ToList();
        }
    }

    public int GetPublishersCount()
    {
        using (CA_Entities db = new CA_Entities ())
        {
            return db.Publishers.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my code behind of the grid control:

```
CA_Entities db = new CA_Entities ();

            // Custom paging, to make DB access & page response quicker
            PublisherDataSource pds = new PublisherDataSource();
            ObjectDataSource ods = new ObjectDataSource();
            ods.EnablePaging = true;
            ods.SelectMethod = "GetPublishers";
            ods.SelectCountMethod = "GetPublishersCount";
            ods.TypeName = pds.ToString();
            ods.MaximumRowsParameterName = "maxRows";
            ods.StartRowIndexParameterName = "startIndex";


            gridPublishers.DataSource = ods;

            gridPublishers.DataBind();
```

This code works brilliantly, but before I finally bind the grid, I want to manipulate the results from the db

eg. Removing certain records, further sorting & filtering of records.

So, Ideally, I'd like to say something like:

```
 List<Publisher> publishers = new List<Publisher>();
            publishers.DataSource = ods;

            // -data manipulation goes here

            gridPublishers.DataSource = publishers;

            gridPublishers.DataBind();
```

But of course, a  can't be DataBound, so...

Can anyone tell me ***how to populate my List of publishers, using the ObjectDataSource ?***

Comment: Why you are implementing paging, GridView already supports it.

Comment: Standard GridView paging still returns the entire db table, and does the paging calculation server side. It takes too long to retrieve all the data, so I need to only return the data we need to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to have to do your data manipulation when fetching the records (inside GetPublishers() function) - this way you will still be able to use ObjectDataSource as your DataSource for the grid.

Alternatively you can try and populate the grid from your custom object (publishers) rather than using ObjectDataSource. You will then have to implement function/s for the gridview paging (gridview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) should do the job)

The simplest example of PageIndexChanging implementation (it's more of a trick than proper implementation really) is

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {        
     gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     gv.DataBind();
  }
```

Although since you're dealing with large data and mentioned performance I'd recommend doing right and fetch only the rows you'll be displaying. The below can help

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx

Comment: Sadly, I think you're right - I'm going to have to do it 'OldSkool' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method?

```
List<Publisher> publishers = (List<Publisher>)ods.Select();
```

> **ObjectDataSource.Select Method**
>
> *Retrieves data from the underlying data storage by calling the method
>   that is identified by the SelectMethod property with the parameters in
>   the SelectParameters collection.*

Comment: Thanks Scheien - the SelectMethod (GetPublishers) is called, but doesn't pass in the parameters [StartIndex] or [MaxRows] which are automatically passed in when 
'gridPublishers.DataSource = ods;
gridPublishers.DataBind();' is called

So, the publishers List still remains null